# Getting the same integral u/v form after applying integration by parts in linear differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

[This is my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdvhx.jpg)

Question:

$$x\log x \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} + y = \log x^2$$

Integrating factor: $$e^{\int p\mathrm{d}x}\ = e^x $$

General Solution:
y(IF) = $$\int \frac{\log x}x e^x \mathrm{d}x+c$$
Applying integration by parts
y(IF) = $$ \log x^2 + \int \frac{\log x}x \mathrm{d}x+ c $$

I'm solving a problem using linear differential equation and I got stuck at the last step. I'm getting the same $u/v$ integral for which I used integration by parts and I'm stuck there.

Comment: There is a mistake in the first step of your solution of the differential equation: $$x\log x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=\log^2x$$ is not equivalent to $$\frac{dy}{dx}+y=\frac{\log x}{x}.$$

Comment: I don't know who edited that but it's $log x^2$

Comment: If it's $\log x^2$, then $\frac{\log x^2}{x\log x}=\frac{2\log x}{x\log x}=\frac{2}{x}.$

Comment: Do you mean $\log(x^2)$ or $(\log x)^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out myself

I just took $$\log(x)^2$$ as t

$$ = t^2 - \int t dt + c$$
$$= t^2 - \frac{t^2}2 + c$$
$$= \frac{2t^2-t^2}2 + c $$
$$= \frac{t^2}2 + c$$
$$= \frac{\log(x)^2}2 + c$$

I hope this is correct

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have an integral of the form
$$\int f(x) f'(x)\mathrm dx=\frac12(f(x))^2+k $$
In your case $f(x)=\log x$, hence:
$$\int\frac{\log x}{x}\mathrm dx=\frac12\log^2 x+k $$